# passing variable to a php class

Tags: php, variables, oauth

I am a beginner in php. and trying to work with Oauth. but this is not the point. the point is following: I have an Oauth class, there are four functions which return urls like this:

```
class tOauth{
    ......
    function accessTokenURL()  {
        return 'http://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token'; 
    }  
    function authenticateURL() { 
        return 'http://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate'; 
    } 
    ......
}
```

this works fine. but now I want these functions to be generic, such that they are suitable for any social sites. this means I have to danymically pass all urls and return them at run time. so I come up something like this:

```
class tOauth{
    ....
    public $accessTokenURL,$authenticateURL;
    function accessTokenURL()  {
        return $this->accessTokenURL; 
    }  
    function authenticateURL() { 
        return $this->authenticateURL; 
    } 
    ....
}
```

and at run time I call them like this:

```
$oauth=new Oauth(key,secret);
$oauth->accessTokenURL='http://www.facebook.com/oauth/access_token';
$oauth->authenticateURL='http://www.facebook.com/oauth/authenticate';
$token=$oauth->requestToken($someurl);
```

but for some reason, this doesn't seems to work. I did not change anything else. it seems I can not daynamically assign variables like this. does any body know what may be the problem? thanks for any tips.

**Update:** whole sample code can be find here: https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth/blob/master/twitteroauth/twitteroauth.php

Comment: You probably need to update `requestToken`'s code with your new changes. If it ain't broke, don't fix it.

Comment: hi,thanks for you comment. but the logic doesn't make sense to me. I create an object of oauth, and immediately after I have those varialbes assgined with values. and then I start calling other methods. this seems does not affect other methods which are called after assigning. does it?

Comment: You are incorrect - it does affect them. You just probably get the wrong variable and all the problems are probably located in the code you are calling, but did not show to us. We can only guess.

Comment: $let me try to find the code....please see the update..

Comment: The common practice is to include code within the question. First of all the code you have linked is not the one you are asking about - it is different (complexity, methods' and member variables' names, and even you did not make member variables public).

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** Your code does not show any details about `requestToken()` method. The following solution gets you access token instead.

You read something you did not set according to your code. Replace the last line with

```
$token=$oauth->accessToken($someurl);
```

and it will work for `accessToken`.

Also consider [inheritance](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php) that will allow you to store common instructions in `tOauth` class and the service-specific ones in separate classes inheriting from it (eg. `Twitter_Oauth` may inherit from your `tOauth` class and have specific URLs set to default from the beginning, without the need to set them every time).

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply. but requestToken() method is going to call accessToken. I don't directly call this method accessToken().

Comment: @Yijie This is something you did not include in your question. Probably the problem lies in the code part you did not show us.

Comment: yea,,,sorry for not being clear eariler..but inheritance is a good idea. I have  not try that. thanks

Comment: @Yijie Sure it is - this is quite a standard in some cases. But first fix what does not work - it should even without inheritance.

Comment: i have updated the whole sampe code.. in case you are interested..thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why not write getter and setter methods for your class variables?

You already have methods, that return accessTokenURL and authentificateURL.

I believe this might work:

```
        class tOauth{
    ....
    public $accessTokenURL,$authenticateURL;
    function accessTokenURL()  {
        return $this->accessTokenURL; 
    }  
    function authenticateURL() { 
        return $this->authenticateURL; 
    }
    function set_accessTokenURL($token)
    {
        $this->accessTokenURL = $token;
    }
    function set_authenticateTokenURL($token)
    {
       $this->authenticateTokenURL = $token;
    }
    ....
    }
```

Comment: Hi,,thans for your reply... I tried setters and did not work though. beside, what is difference between using setters and direct assignments in php?

Comment: Well, since your variables are already declared public, there's no difference really. But sometimes setters seem to work while accessing class variables directly is kind of a hassle.